# Will settings stored via SharedPreference be included when we export the app (for release)

Tags: android, release, sharedpreferences

I have developed my first Android app and I'm thinking about sending it to my friends who owns Android phones (I am using Nokia 5230 :p)

I have made the release version of the app using the `Export` wizard of Eclipse.

In my app, during startup, it would get some settings via `SharedPreferences` - (MODE_Private). And these settings are overwritten when user presses a button(later on, with the user entered settings).

So, my question is, when I send this release version of my app, would it contain the settings that I have presently stored ?
At the moment, I don't need the settings (that I saved while testing in my AVD) to be included in the release apk file.

- If included by default(while creating the release version), how do I detach it. I mean what to do so that it won't be included.
- If it is not included by default, I would also like to know how to include it with the release version, say for my future reference (I mean, I might need this approach in my next app)

The settings are obtained like this way:

```
SharedPreferences settings =  
        getSharedPreferences("myABCapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
String strUser = settings.getString("username", "");
//...
```

Settings are overwritten(saved at runtime) by user in this way:

```
//...
SharedPreferences settings =  
        getSharedPreferences("myABCapp", MODE_PRIVATE);  

SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
prefEditor.putString("username", strNewUsername);
//...

prefEditor.commit();
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You have to detect first launch and create your initial settings in SharedPrefs, from within your app.

You can replicate what a new user will see by Settings/Applications/Manage Applications//Clear Data ... and then launch your app

PVS

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't got the part of clearing the settings, that you mentioned above. I just gone through the whole sets of menus and configurations to find out what you mentioned there. After several minutes, I found that you were talking about the `Settings` in my AVD. I have gone till `Settings/Applications/Manage Applications`. After that it displays list of apps installed in my AVD. So I clicked on my app, and it showed `Uninstall` and `Force Stop` buttons enabled. But there is `Clear Cache` and `Clear Defaults` buttons which are disabled. So, what to do ?